# Communication between databases of different microservices

Tags: postgresql

There is an application with microservices. At first there was only one microservice - “payment coordination”, now “time tracking” has appeared. I would like to separate the databases so that they are independent of each other; at any time you can restore the database of one of the microservices. These microservices have in common a list of users and a list of cities. How to deal with the database correctly? to share or not? how to configure connections between databases?

Comment: Sharing a database defies the purpose of microservices. You could use logical replication to distribute the tables that the databases should have in common.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed! Configured, it works!